# How can i publish Page using TOM.net api?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Is it possible to publish a Page by using Tom.net API in SDL Tridion 2011?

Comment: Yes. Care to tell us what you tried?

Comment: @NunoLinhares: i want to write an event where whenever a page is deleted or created, a sitemap page gets published.

Comment: Cool. Google is your friend: http://codedweapon.com/2012/03/tridion-publishengine/

Comment: @NunoLinhares:: thanks , But this page does not explain how to publish a page using TOM.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nuno mentioned, use `PublishEngine.Publish` and refer the syntax and example

### Syntax:

```
PublishEngine.Publish(
    new IdentifiableObject[] { linkedComponent },
    engine.PublishingContext.PublishInstruction,
    new List() { engine.PublishingContext.PublicationTarget });
```

Do something like this:-

```
private void Publish(IdentifiableObject item, PublicationTarget publicationTarget, bool rollBackOnFailure, bool includeComponentLinks)
{
    IEnumerable<IdentifiableObject> items = new List<IdentifiableObject>() { item };    
    IEnumerable<PublicationTarget> targets = new List<PublicationTarget>() { publicationTarget };
    PublishInstruction instruction = new PublishInstruction(item.Session)
    {
        DeployAt = DateTime.Now,
        RenderInstruction = new RenderInstruction(item.Session)
        {
            RenderMode = RenderMode.Publish
        },
        ResolveInstruction = new ResolveInstruction(item.Session)
        {
            IncludeComponentLinks = includeComponentLinks
        },
        RollbackOnFailure = rollBackOnFailure,
        StartAt = DateTime.MinValue
    };
    PublishEngine.Publish(items, instruction, targets);
}
```

***Contents is copied from **[How to Publish Stuff Programmatically](http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/04/how-to-publish-stuff-programmatically.html#!/2012/04/how-to-publish-stuff-programmatically.html)** blog*

Comment: Thought it looked familiar :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `PublishEngine.Publish`, follow Intellisense from there. You'll need to provide Render and Resolve instructions, as well as the usual details like Target, start date/time, etc.

The documentation has samples, various blogs have samples, and Visual Studio should help you find what you need.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being rough, but this is a really simple task. Lesson #1: Tridion Content Manager Explorer uses the same API that you do, if it can do something, then you can do it too.